# Must declare the table variable "@p0"

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am using `ExecuteSqlCommand` of entity framework core to delete all the rows of a table.
However, I am getting an error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the table variable "@p0".'`

Here is my code:

```
 public static void ExecuteDeleteSQL(ShoppingCartDbContext context, string tableName)
 {
     context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"Delete from {tableName}"); //This line throws the error
 }
```

It is called here:

```
ExecuteDeleteSQL(context, "[dbo].[ShoppingCartItems]");
```

I am using .NET Core 2 with EntityFrameworkCore

I've installed the following nuget packages:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you have to pass at least one parameter to `ExecuteSqlCommand` even though my query doesn't use any parameters.
And the annoying bit is that it doesn't complain during compile time.

```
//passing at least one parameter    
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"Delete from {tableName}",tableName);
```

***EDIT:***

There is a similar issue reported in GitHub and currently under consideration:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10956